# DotSpatial map not inside DotSpatial.Controls

Tags: c#, dotspatial

I'm trying to install DotSpatial using c# WinForm, to take a look at the Map control. I've installed DotSpatial.Controls using nuget from VS. Installation successfully. Added inside my toolBar the DotSpatial.Control.dll which is inside ../bin/debug folder, but, just 3 controls are added: AppManager, SpatialDockManager, SpatialHeaderControl.

Why is Map control not there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are most likely having is that the Controls library has many dependencies that are necessary in order to use the Map control correctly.  If you just download one dll, it won't be enough in order to get all the dependencies that you need.  Here are the steps I took to be able to add a map control using version 1.9.0:

1. Use GitHub [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) to clone the DotSpatial\DotSpatial project.
2. Open the Dotspatial\DotSpatial\Source\DotSpatial.sln in visual studio.
3. Right click on Solution 'DotSpatial' in Solution Explorer -> Build Solution
4. Close the solution and switch to your own project or solution.
5. Right Click on References in the Solution Explorer -> Add Reference
6. Browse to the Dotspatial\DotSpatial\Source\bin\Debug folder.
7. Select the modules you want and then add them as references.
   [image: References]
8. Right click in the Toolbox window -> Add Tab, name it DotSpatial.
9. Right click the DotSpatial Tab -> Choose Items ...
10. Click the browse button
    [image: Click Browse]
11. Navigate to the Dotspatial\DotSpatial\Source\bin\Debug folder for instance.
12. Select the DotSpatial.Controls.dll
13. Sort the controls by Namespace (ensuring all the DotSpatial controls are selected)
    [image]
14. Click Ok to add them.
15. Now you should be able to drag and drop the map onto your project.

As an added note, when trying to add the controls and drag and drop the map without setting up my project references first and I ended up with an IO Error saying that it could not find the file for DotSpatial.Projections.dll.

Anyway, I'm not 100% sure that this was the issue you were having, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ted appears to be correct in that the issue is with the dependencies of the Map Control.  The problem is when the packages are installed via NuGet, the various dlls are all installed in different directories, and the Map Control can't find them.

The solution is to copy all the dlls into a common directory, prior to adding the DotSpatial.Controls dll to the toolbox (steps 8-15 in Ted's answer).

Or you could use Ted's solution and download the source and compile the source.